# Tick sound develops after riding 5-10 min

Tags: noise

I have a single tick sound that occurs when pressure is applied to the right pedal while riding, but it’s not audible until 5-10 minutes into a ride. Any ideas what could cause the time delay?

Comment: Can you check the pedal platform-axle and the axle-crankarm and the crankarms-BB axle for play ?   Is there a specific crank angle for the noise ?   Does noise appear only on full rotations vs oscillating over the same sector of rotation?   If you push down hard or softly, does the noise change at all ?

Comment: @Criggie I’m not seeing any play. Noise occurs when crank is from the 12 pm-3 o’clock part of the pedal stroke. It’s only on full rotations while pedaling consistently. The noise gets louder when going up an incline and force.

Comment: The symptoms sound like what I experienced once. The noise disappeared after I tightened the pedals

Comment: Curious: is the bike stored inside (warm temps) and then being ridden outside (presumably cooler temps in the northern hemisphere's autumn)?

Comment: @PaulH You are correct

Answer (score 3):

If you have cheap regular platform pedals, check the screws that secures the cage to the center portion. Check both sides. When you apply force to the right side you are releasing the tension on the left side (which can generate a sound just as much as increasing tension)!

Check crank bolts are tight if it applies. Check for play in cranks(wobbling can cause chain-rub once per revolution) and pedals. Check **skewers** are tight if it's a QR bike!!

Tighten/check tightness of all bolts on the stem.

The list goes on and on(*), but I have experienced ticks/creaks fitting that description from all mentioned areas.

(*)Seat tube-clamp, lose spoke, rubbing chains, rubbing wires, damaged frames.. the list never ends until you find the cause.